# React-Native Picker is not dropdown

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to make a **dropdown** select box. I'm using react-native's **Picker**.

I'm using the following code:

```
<Picker mode={"dropdown"} selectedValue={"test2"} style={{height: 50, width: 125}}>
  <Picker.Item label="test" value="test"/>
  <Picker.Item label="test2" value="test2"/>
  <Picker.Item label="test3" value="test3"/>
  <Picker.Item label="test4" value="test4"/>
</Picker>
```

The Picker still appears to not be a dropdown.
I'm using a IPhone X on the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

The `mode` props is only supported on Android. From the docs:

> `mode`
>
> On Android, specifies how to display the selection items when the user taps on the picker:
>
> - 'dialog': Show a modal dialog. This is the default.
> - 'dropdown': Shows a dropdown anchored to the picker view

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#mode

Answer (score 0):

I found out that mode only applies to Android. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select did the job.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing this issue here is the best solution that works for both IOS and Android : https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-element-dropdown

```
import { Dropdown } from "react-native-element-dropdown";
```

I tried so many package but this is by far the best one and it's so customizable and easy to use. i wish i found this early when i started working on my project.
Thank me later.